# Homeup button on XML

Tags: android, android-layout

How to achieve below type of UI, It has one home up button and and imageView. I don't want to use coordinate layout as this whole page scrolls up instead of collapsing image.
[image]

Home up button overlaps entire image

Comment: You can set the image as background & add your button

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with linear layout only for that part.

Comment: Yes. But how will I get HomeUp button then

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

</FrameLayout>
```